# Deserializing JSON issue

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I need to deserialize just part of a JSON string returned from a server. The 'myData' portion in the JSON string below.

My JSON string is structured as follows.

```
{
    "data": {
        "CODE": {
            "someData": {
                "h": "foo",
                "id": "City",
                "lat": "11.11111"
            },
            "feedMe": [
                [
                    {
                        "myData": {
                            "item1": "a",
                            "item2": "b",
                            "item3": "c"
                        },
                        "moreData": {}
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

In Unity there is the JSONutility.FromJson method
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html

but unsure how I would either

1 pass only the 'myData' portion to this method.

or

2 Deserialize the entire string

Comment: why is there an array in an array?

Comment: The unity reference does not show a way to do such thing, you will need to deserialize the whole object.

Comment: Why an array in a array? Same question I asked:)

Comment: Updated question based on comments. In order to deserialize the entire string, don't I need to first create a class with the same structure to use as an object type when I call JSONutility.FromJson?

Comment: Plug your JSON into [this site](http://json2csharp.com/), and compare the resulting classes with the code you're using.

Comment: If you are using `Json.NET` refer to [this](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm). I don't think it's possible with Unity's Json Utility.

Answer (score 1):

An alternativ to using `JsonUtility` there is good old [`SimpleJSON`](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON) which allows you to only access a certain field of your json like e.g.

```
var N = JSON.Parse(the_JSON_string);
var myData = N["data"]["CODE"]["feedMe"][0][0];
var item2 = myData["item2"].Value;
```

---

In general the simplest way to get the needed c# class structure for your json is always using [`json2csharp`](http://json2csharp.com) and make all classes `[Serializable]` and remove the `{get; set;}` in order to use fields instead of properties. Something like this

```
[Serializable]
public class SomeData
{
    public string h;
    public string id;
    public string lat;
}

[Serializable]
public class CODE
{
    public SomeData someData;
    public List<List<MyData>> feedMe;
}

[Serializable]
public class MyData
{
    public string item1;
    public string item2;
    public string item3;
}

[Serializable]
public class Data
{
    public CODE CODE;
}

[Serializable]
public class RootObject
{
    public Data data;
}
```

Instead of `List<T>` you can also use `T[]` if you like. And the class names actually don't matter but the structure and field names have to match.

and then use

```
var root = JsonUtility.FromJson<RootObject>(THE_JSON_STRING);
var myData = root.data.CODE.feedMe[0][0];
var item2 = myData.item2;
```

---

As already comented however there is a nested array in your array .. not sure if this is intended.

Answer (score 0):

well, use one of the powerful json nuget -newtonsoft.json , then in your code you can iterate the values like below

```
var files = JObject.Parse(YourJSON);
var recList = files.SelectTokens("$..data").ToList();
foreach (JObject obj in recList.Children())
 {
   foreach (JProperty prop in obj.Children())
      {
        var key = prop.Name.ToString();
        var value = prop.Value.ToString();
         //Do your stuffs here
      }

  }
```

Answer (score -2):

JsonUtility not work whit json files, this only for save and load basic public variables of some class. Asset Store have many frameworks for parse json. p.s. your json is strange, [] its array and you have `feedMe:[[{myData, moreData}]]`. One array whene just one object in array... parse confusing.